# react native one variable update is other variable value

Tags: variables, react-native, updates

I want to store one state variable value temporarily and change in only temporarily variable.

in my code original variable is var1 and temp variable is var2.

> After update var2 value var1 value is automatically update.

**Before update var2 value:-**

[image]

**After update var2 value:-**

[image]

**My Code:-**

```
class DemoScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            var1: {
                data:'variable 1 Data'
            },
            var2: {
                data:'variable 2 Data'
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        alert("var1 : " + this.state.var1.data + "\nvar2 : " + this.state.var2.data);
        this.setState({var2:this.state.var1});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{
                        var var2 = this.state.var2;
                        var2.data = "value changed";
                        this.setState({var2:var2});
                    }}>
                    <Text>Change Value for var2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{
                        alert("var1 : " + this.state.var1.data + "\nvar2 : " + this.state.var2.data);
                    }}>
                    <Text>Display Values</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

why it is happening?
how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens here is that you're setting `var2` to the reference of `var1` not its value, that's why that happens, what you need to do is to replace that line

```
this.setState({var2:this.state.var1});
```

With this line:

```
this.setState({var2: Object.assign({}, this.state.var1)});
```

Using `Object.assign` will clone the value of your object without returning its reference. Always remember `Obj1 = Obj2` means that `Obj1` equals the reference of `Obj2` which means that the both of them considered the same object